# Magento 2 Commerce. Delete/Remove a scheduled update (Content Staging)

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Commerce comes with a feature called [Content Staging](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/content-staging.html). 
As far as I can see there is no clear way to delete an update.

I had a **scheduled update** with a catalog rule associated to it. After I deleted the rule the **update** was removed as well(or at least is not visible in the grid)

I now have a **scheduled update** with no *objects*(cart rules, catalog rules etc) assigned to it(I removed them) yet the update is still there.

Questions:

- How do I remove a scheduled update?
- If there are any reasoning behind a scheduled update can not be removed?

Comment: Any findings on this?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri as far as I remember the strategy we ended up using is removing all changes from a scheduled update, at some point the scheduled update was removed, via cron I think
I have some work coming up on content staging in the near future and check on this.

Comment: Any luck??????????

Comment: do you have any findings about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete a scheduled update with a start time minor than current time.

**vendor/magento/module-staging/Block/Adminhtml/Update/Entity/RemoveButton.php**

```
private function canRemoveFromUpdate()
{
    $updateId = $this->updateIdProvider->getUpdateId();
    if (null !== $updateId) {
        $update = $this->updateRepository->get($updateId);
        $startTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp($update->getStartTime());
        $currentDateTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
        return $currentDateTime < $startTime;
    }
    return false;
}
```